# Too many re-render using context provider and localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this problem `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` with my `useLocalStorage` custom hook.

I can't find a solution, there is no use of useEffect or any loop in the code.

Here is the custom hook for useLocalStorage:

```
function useLocalStorage(itemName, initialValue) {

  const [item, setItem] = React.useState(initialValue);
  
  const localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem(itemName);
  let parsedItem;

  if (!localStorageItem) {
    localStorage.setItem(itemName, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
    parsedItem = initialValue;
  } else {
    parsedItem = JSON.parse(localStorageItem);
  }
  setItem(parsedItem);
  
  const saveItem = (newItem) => {
      const stringifiedItem = JSON.stringify(newItem);
      localStorage.setItem(itemName, stringifiedItem);
      setItem(newItem);
  };

  return {
    item,
    saveItem,
  };
}

export { useLocalStorage };
```

Here is the context provider, if I delete the line where I call `useLocalStorage`, the error disappears, so the problem is with the `useLocalStorage`.

```
import react from 'react';
import { useLocalStorage } from './useLocalStorage';
import * as utils from '../utils'; 

const AppContext = react.createContext();

function AppProvider(props) {

    const {
        item: expenses,
        saveItem: saveExpense,
    } = useLocalStorage('ITEMS_v1', []);

    const addExpense = (name, value, date) => {
        const newExpenses = [...expenses];
        newExpenses.push({
          name,
          value,
          date,
        });
        saveExpense(newExpenses);
      };

    const deleteExpense = (name) => {
        const expenseIndex = expenses.findIndex(expense => expense.name === name);
        const newExpenses = [...expenses];
        newExpenses.splice(expenseIndex, 1);
        saveExpense(newExpenses);
    };

    const today = utils.getToday();

    return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{
        today,
        addExpense,
        deleteExpense,
    }}>
        {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `setItem(parsedItem)` in the body of the hook, so everytime function run `setItem(parsedItem)` will be invoked which will again call `setItem(parsedItem)` and this will lead to infinite loop.

Never update state in the body of the function. use `useEffect` hook to update the state initially.

```js
function useLocalStorage(itemName, initialValue) {

  const [item, setItem] = React.useState(initialValue);
  React.useEffect(()=>{
     const localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem(itemName);
     let parsedItem;

     if (!localStorageItem) {
        localStorage.setItem(itemName, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
        parsedItem = initialValue;
     } else {
        parsedItem = JSON.parse(localStorageItem);
     }
     setItem(parsedItem);

  },[])
 
  
  const saveItem = (newItem) => {
      const stringifiedItem = JSON.stringify(newItem);
      localStorage.setItem(itemName, stringifiedItem);
      setItem(newItem);
  };

  return {
    item,
    saveItem,
  };
}

export { useLocalStorage };
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the problem is coming from calling the `setItem` directly in the `useLocalStorage`. your code will most likely work if you wrap this part:

```js
const localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem(itemName);
  let parsedItem;

  if (!localStorageItem) {
    localStorage.setItem(itemName, JSON.stringify(initialValue));
    parsedItem = initialValue;
  } else {
    parsedItem = JSON.parse(localStorageItem);
  }
  setItem(parsedItem);
```

in a useEffect hook with an empty dependency array.

Comment: because each time it reaches `setItem` it will trigger a render so the function gets called again.